# Actions in NetBeans module - context menu, main menu

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, action, netbeans-plugins

I am developing NetBeans module and I have declared an action (using annotations, they are translated to layer.xml record) which works with my custom project type (EsperProject class):

```
@ActionID(category = "Run", id = "my.package.RunEsperAction")
@ActionRegistration(displayName = "My Action", asynchronous=true)
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Menu/BuildProject", position = 0)
})
public final class RunEsperAction implements ActionListener {

    private final EsperProject project;

    public RunEsperAction(EsperProject project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
       // do sth with project
    }
}
```

I can run the action from the BuildProject Menu (which is actualy Run menu), but i CANNOT make it work in two cases I need (both called asynchronously as declared in the annotation):

1. I'd like to run the action from the project context menu.
2. I need to have the action triggered when my EsperProject is run
   from the main menu item "Run Main Project".

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the first point: To run the action from the context menu, we must add it to the getActions() method of the project root node, something like this:

```
class RootNode extends FilterNode {
    @Override
    public Action[] getActions(boolean arg0) {
        List<Action> nodeActions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        nodeActions.addAll(Utilities.actionsForPath("Actions/MyCategoryInLayer"));
        return nodeActions.toArray(new Action[nodeActions.size()]);
    }
}
```

The action appears in the context menu of the project and is run asynchronously. However, overriding "Run main project" is still imposible for me. I try the simmilar aproach but this fails:

```
@Override
public void invokeAction(String actionName, Lookup lookup) throws IllegalArgumentException {

if (actionName.equalsIgnoreCase(ActionProvider.COMMAND_RUN)) {
    List<? extends Action> runActions = Utilities.actionsForPath("Actions/Run");
        for (Action action : runActions) {
            action.actionPerformed(null);
        }
}
```

with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openide.util.actions.ActionInvoker$ActionRunnable.needsToBeSynchronous(ActionInvoker.java:147)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1.I'd like to run the action from the project context menu.

It will be possible just by adding @ActionReference(path = "Project/Actions", position = 0) to @ActionReferences